# Return only a range of cells (within desired index range) from a function in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, indexing, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

If I have a function that returns a row of cells (for instance from ImportHTML), the results will always return 9 cells and I need the function to only return the cells from A2:A5 of the results, how can I trim the results to only give me the cells within the indexes that I need?

I need this to work inline, and bonus points if you can do it without using Query, because this will be on a huge spreadsheet with tens of thousands of rows, and performance will be a factor.

Comment: A2:A5 is column not a row

Comment: I think this is rows, A2:A5, because for columns A2:E2

Comment: Yes you are correct. I meant A2:E2, not A2:A5. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> If I have a function that returns a row of cells

for columns **B:E**:

```
=QUERY(your-formula-here, "select Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5", 0)
```

without query:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(OFFSET(your-formula-here,,1), 9^9, 4)
```

in array:

```
={INDEX(your-formula-here,,2), INDEX(your-formula-here,,3),
  INDEX(your-formula-here,,4), INDEX(your-formula-here,,5)}
```

an overkill:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(your-formula-here,,1), your-formula-here, {2,3,4,5}, 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 =query({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},"Select * limit 5")
```

The Result:

```
 {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Change {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9} to your data source, for example from Range, HTML or importrange

or you use like this:

```
=query(query({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},"Select * offset 1"), "Select * limit 4")
```

or

```
=query({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},"Select * limit 4 offset 1")
```

Both give the Result:

```
{2,3,4,5}
```

or

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(offset({1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},1 ,0),4,1)
```

The Result:

```
{2,3,4,5}
```